# Proof that given $y\geq x$, $\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+4}} \geq \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Given $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x\leq y$, then $$\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+4}} \geq \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}$$
Any hint?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I’m sure there are people able to prove it. Was that really what you wanted to ask?

Comment: 1/sqrt(1+4/x²) is strictly increasing

Comment: The function $\sqrt{x^2+4}=\|(x,2)\|$ is convex, hence, the derivative is an increasing function.

Answer (score 5):

Let $x = 2\tan a$ and $y = 2\tan b$ such that $a,b \in (-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$. ( tan obtains all possible values in this interval)

In this interval $\tan$ is increasing. So, $\boxed{x\le y \iff a\le b}$

Now, $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+4}} = \frac{2\tan a}{2\sec a} = \sin a$. Similarly $\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+4}} = \sin b$

In the interval $(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$, $\sin $ is also increasing. So $\boxed{a\le b \iff \sin a\le \sin b \text{ or } \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+4}} \le\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+4}}}$